# Is there any reason for the mass of the electrons?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, elementary-particles

I've recently read Feynman's QED in which he mentioned the possibility that the seemingly random numbers that correspond to the mass of the electron and heavier charged particles (mu and tau electrons) could be the result of something even smaller making up and governing their mass. Is there any theory or experiment that goes further into this?

Comment: If there is even the slightest hint, we would have a major announcement and put it on Wikipedia. No, we do not.

Comment: The Standard Model says that the mass of the electron is determined by its Yukawa coupling to the Higgs field. Unfortunately, it offers no explanation for the strength of that coupling.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39590/2451 and links therein.