# Is there scientific work about the inner structure of the electron and its magnetic and electric fields?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electrons, electric-fields

Since the electron posseses permanently an electric and a magnetic field to search for a model of the constituents of this inner structure and the two fields should be good scientific area of research. This model has to explain not only both field components of the electron but also both components of the EM radiation.

Was scientific work done about the inner structure of the electron and its magnetic and electric fields? Are there any ideas?

Comment: All the experimental evidence is that it has no structure. This, of course, takes the form of a limit but if quantum mechanics is fundamental there is no obvious way to see how there could be structure at or below that limit.

Comment: @dmckee Which science is fundamental? May be mathematics. History teaches us that apparently nothing in physics is forever. QM is a step to explain some phenomena in our world. Science lives from the humans curiosity. And model creation is one important step. Remember how Maxwell arrives his theory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39590/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7322/50583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still ongoing experiments that look for a possible inner structure of the electron. Mostly, these experiments aim at a measurement of the electron dipole moment for comparison with theoretical predictions (Standard Model, Super Symmetry,...). See for instance the group of [Ed Hinds](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/centre-for-cold-matter/research/edm/) at Imperial College London and the [ACME Collaboration](http://laserstorm.harvard.edu/edm//index.html) (Dave DeMille, John Doyle, Gerard Gabrielse at Yale and Harvard).